# Issue featch with where condition in titanium alloy

Tags: backbone.js, titanium, titanium-mobile, fetch, titanium-alloy

I have two pick lists in my app, both are dynamic values coming from DB. The values in to second pick list are displayed based the value selected in first pick list. So change event of first pick list the second pick list values should dynamically change with out refreshing the page.

My code is as follows,

**Controller:**

```
      $.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    languageid = e.row.title;
    alert("language is : "+ languageid);
    movie.fetch({query: "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id = '"+languageid+"';"});
    var column = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();
    movie.each(function(model){
          var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
                         title: model.get("movieName")
                     });
           column.addRow(row);
    });
    $.picker1.columns = [column];
   });
```

**View:**

```
 <Alloy>
    <Collection src="UserLanguage"/>
    <Collection src="movies"/>
    <Window class="container">
    <Picker id="picker"/>
    <Picker id="picker1"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**Style:**

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"black"
}

"#picker": {
    width: '90%',
    top: '25dp'
}

"#picker1": {
    width: '90%',
    top: '100dp'
}
```

**Model**

```
exports.definition = {
    config : {
        "columns": {
            "id": "text",
            "movieName": "text"
        },
        "adapter": {
            "type": "sql",
            "collection_name": "movies"
        }
    }
};
```

**Screenshot result**

[image]

The select roe count is correct but the text is not visible. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, let's start from beginning because current solution is too messy...

**View:** (Make sure that you have got models/Movies.js)

```
<Alloy>
    <Collection src="UserLanguage"/>
    <Collection src="Movies"/>

    <Window class="container">
        <Picker id="picker"/>
        <Picker id="picker1"/>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**Controller:** (The problem was that @Coyote selects data from table called `movie` not `movies`). So it should look like this:

```
var movies = Alloy.Collections.Movies;

$.picker.addEventListener("change", function(e) {
    var column = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();

    movies.fetch({
        query: {
            statement: "SELECT * FROM movies WHERE id = ?;",
            params: [e.row.title] // How can be `title` an id?
        }
    });

    movies.each(function(model) {
        var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
            title: model.get("movieName")
        });

        column.addRow(row);
    });

    $.picker1.columns = [column];
});
```

Comment: I am not sure ,but `e.row.title` is probably null which it can not be. https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-17263

Comment: The question is why is `e.row.title` empty (null)? What about `e.value`? I really don't know what you want to do ,but basically here `params: [e.row.title]` must be some value not null.

Comment: Now I'm not getting the error, but in second pick list 2 rows are selected but for some reason the column titles are not visible. Only blank rows are showing which I attached in screenshot in my question. Why?

Comment: Try `console.log("Row title: " + model.get("movieName"));` in `movies.each`.

Comment: It is printing null in title, [INFO] :   Row title: null
[INFO] :   Row title: null

Comment: See, so you have no value in `model.get("movieName");` -> `movieName`. Check whether it is being saved correctly...

Answer (score 2):

Just use the query parameter passed to fetch function :

```
$.picker.addEventListener('change',function(e){
    languageid = e.row.title;
    //alert("language is : "+ languageid);
    movie.fetch({query: "SELECT * FROM movie WHERE id = '"+languageid+"';"});
    var column = Ti.UI.createPickerColumn();
    movie.each(function(model){
          var row = Ti.UI.createPickerRow({
                         title: model.get("movieName");
                     });
           column.addRow(row);
    });
    $.picker1.columns = [column];
});
```

Comment: Now the rows are showing correctly but the row title text is not visible. What is the issue. Is that styling issue?

Comment: The problem might be in `movieName` property. Is it correct name?

Comment: There is no issue with movieName property. I have updated the question and screenshot. Plase suggest me why was the text is not visible